# ADO.NET Entity Framework and ADO.NET Entity Data Model?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, entity-data-model

This is confusing me a bit... When people talk about ADO.NET Entity Framework are they actually talking about ADO.NET Entity Data Model?

Comment: The Entity Data Model is *part* of the Entity Framework (which is the model, the modelling tools, and the runtime)

Answer (score 2):

No, the Entity Framework includes several components such as the Entity Data Model Wizard, which allows you to create an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (via Database First or Design First workflow, or Code First). The data model is stored in an EDMX file (for Database First or Design First) and can be viewed and edited in the Entity Framework Designer. For Code First, your data model is your c# classes along with a DbContext class.

For more info, see this video:
Entity Framework Development Workflows
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj590134