# ADO.NET Entity Data Model vs DataSet vs Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, dataset, entity-data-model

So I know there are few ways to access data from the database.

I worked a bit with ADO.NET Entity Data Model, `DataSet` and Entity Framework. But still I can't quiet grasp what is what. I know the basic stuff about each of them.

So now I have a few questions. Here we go (using Visual Studio):

1. In Visual Studio when I go to `add -> new item -> Data`, I can choose between ADO.NET Entity Data Model and `DataSet`. Is `DataSet` part of ADO.NET technology?
2. When people talk about ADO.NET Entity Data Model are they actually talking about ADO.NET Entity Framework since Entity Framework is in the background of ADO.NET Data Model? (you have to add Entity Framework in references to use ADO.NET Entity Data Model)
3. Is ADO.NET Entity Data model part of ADO.NET Entity Framework?

The third way that I used to communicate with my database was by using code first and then adding package: TOOLS -> Manage NuGetPackages for solution -> nuget.org -> EntityFramework (Install). After that I was able to use MyContext: DbContext and access my database.

Now, I can actually communicate with my database by using :

1. ADO.NET Entity Data Model (ADO.NET Entity Framework?)
2. DataSet (Part of ADO.NET?)
3. Entity Framework ("pure" entity framework?)

I know that I've thrown in a lot of stuff in this question(s).

I hope that someone can help me with this.

Comment: As I already mentioned in a [comment to your **other question** on the same topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345135/ado-net-entity-framework-and-ado-net-entity-data-model) - **Entity Framework** is the whole thing - the runtime, the design time modelling tools, and of course the whole concept of the "Entity Data Model". You cannot have an ADO.NET Entity Data Model without Entity Framework, and vice-versa - those are tightly integrated. `DataSet` is a whole different story - based on untyped columns and rows, it's much closer to underlying relational database model

Comment: I'm starting to understand the whole thing. I just got confused since I have to use all of this for my projects.Thank you for your quick reply.